# yii route with unlimited parameters

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, frameworks

I want to be able to separate parameters of actions by `/` in `URL` for `Yii2 Framework`,

E.g: `http://localhost/advanced/backend/web/controller/action/parameter1/parameter2`

Here `parameter(1,2,...)` are not just `id` and `integer` numbers
I searched a lot across internet and also here but I didn't found an useful answer that work ,I hvave tried this:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

but it doesn't work
and I had to pass parameters as get variables to work

```
http://localhost/advanced/backend/web/controller/action/?parameterName=value
```

Can anyone help me, its necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

With 2 params (or any known number really) you could extend this pattern:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<param1:\w+>/<param2:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

With unlimited number of params, I don't think it works with the UrlRule-class. You need to write your own class and replace. Don't see why you would like to have unlimited number of params anyway. Also an url can't be unlimited long.

--- Edit ---

If you want 4 parameters you could use default values in function instead of writing a new UrlRule class

```
public function actionMyController($param1=null, $param2=null, $param3=null, $param4=null)
```

Comment: actually i don't want to have infinite parameters i mean 2-4 parameter by unlimited,However i search a lot ,you right , for unlimited params i should write my own UrlRule Class,Thanks for your good answer

Comment: you have to define your URL with YII routes, otherwise it will route.